# Pre Define Password for User created through Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am currently working on a Powershell Script that asks me to Enter "FirstName", "LastName" and the "Department" to add Users in Active Directory, add them to Certain Groups, create their own Folder and so on.

The only thing that isn't working is to pre define a default password, that every user should get while beeing created through the script. I managed to make it work through another field that requires you to enter a password.

But since the user has to change the password once he is login in for the first time, i would like to avoid entering the same password all the time.

Thanks in advance!

`Clear Host
    Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------------------"
    $Vorname = Read-Host "FirstName"

    Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------------------"
    $Nachname = Read-Host "LastName"

    Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------------------"
    $Department = Read-Host "Department"`

```
    #Variables
    $OU = "ou=Sales,dc=contoso,dc=local"
    $Domain = "contoso.local"
    $group = "Sales-Alle"
    $verteiler = "Sales-Mail"



    $DisplayName = $Vorname + " " + $Nachname
    $userLogonName = $Vorname + "." + $Nachname
    $SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Pa$$w0rd" -AsPlainText -Force

    New-ADUser -Name $Vorname `
    -SamAccountName $userLogonName `
    -GivenName $Vorname `
    -Surname $Nachname `
    -DisplayName $DisplayName `
    -Department $Department `
    -Path $OU `
    -AccountPassword $SecurePass `
    -Enabled $true `
    -UserPrincipalName ($userLogonName + "@" + $Domain) `
    -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$securepass = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter Password:"` to ask for a password. If you want to simply generate a password and you could use the [System.Web.Security.Membership class' GeneratePassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Web_Security_Membership_GeneratePassword_System_Int32_System_Int32_) method to pick one for you.

```
#Add the assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
#18 characters with a minimum of 4 non alphanumeric
$unsecurepass = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(18,4)
#convert to a securestring
$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $unsecurepass -AsPlainText -Force
#give the initial credential to the person running the script
Write-Output "User's One Time Password: $unsecurepass"
#Clear the unsecure password
Remove-Variable unsecurepass
#continue with New-ADUser
```